# SSRS trouble using DateDiff in a IIF statement

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS returns an #error when the statement is `False`, but `No Start Date` when the statement is True. I tested and the DateDiff is correct in the False side of the statement. I'm not sure which direction to go from here. Thank you.

```
=IIF(Fields!JobOrderIssueDate.Value = "", "No Start Date",DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!ProjectedConstEndDate.Value))
```

Comment: questions seeking debugging help should include a minimum verifiable example. The minimum code required for us to reproduce your issue locally.

Comment: @BlakeYarbrough: Ok, thanks. I will update.

Comment: You are returning two different data types from your `IIF` -- a string when the condition is TRUE and a DATE when the condition is FALSE.  Wherever you happen to be using this expression, a STRING is expected which is why you see `#error` when the condition is TRUE.  What are you trying to do with this expression?  Is the default value for a parameter?

Comment: I am trying to first, check a field to see if it is empty. If it is empty, I want to return a string. If it is not empty, I want to return the field (which is a date) in MM/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing data types in your `IIF` returning either a STRING or a DATE depending on the condition of the `IIF`.  This is not going to work.

One approach would be to convert the data type returned by the FALSE condition so that it is also returns a STRING (using `CStr()`):

```
=IIF(Fields!JobOrderIssueDate.Value = "", "No Start Date",CStr( DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!ProjectedConstEndDate.Value)))
```

or you could gain a little more control over formatting (using `FormatDateTime()`):

```
=IIF(Fields!JobOrderIssueDate.Value = "", "No Start Date",FormatDateTime( DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!ProjectedConstEndDate.Value), DateFormat.ShortDate))
```

Answer (score -1):

Change format to compare between data and string also will not work, the best method to inspect the Date field with `IsDate` function

```
=IIF(IsDate(Fields!JobOrderIssueDate.Value), DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!ProjectedConstEndDate.Value), "No Start Date")
```