# RDLC Today() - DateTimeValue

Tags: c#, rdlc

I need to find # of days difference from some old date to Today's date in RDLC Report.

I tried looking in `DateDiff()` and made some Expressions for getting output but it shows Error only.

Following Expressions I tried till now

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,CDate(Today()),Fields!AnotherDate.Value)
=DateDiff("d",CDate(Today()),Fields!AnotherDate.Value)

=DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!AnotherDate.Value)
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Today(),Fields!AnotherDate.Value)

=DateDiff("d",Now(),Fields!AnotherDate.Value)
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Now(),Fields!AnotherDate.Value)
```

Please tell how can I do this in RDLC ?

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you put any effort into researching this before you asked it here.

Comment: what error you got while report generation?

Comment: I tried looking many sites even understood DateDiff() function on msdn site and codeProject site and many more. but didn't find answer

Comment: @KD It doesn't show error but shows `#Value` in Report

Comment: try following link and provided IIF just in case your comparison values doesn't have correct value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276247/ssrs-trouble-using-datediff-in-a-iif-statement

Comment: @KD `=CStr(DateDiff("d",Today(),Fields!AnotherDate.Value))` I Tried this but it shows red line under `()` of `Today()`